# How to correctly use the linear-gradient while styling GNOME shell?

Tags: gnome, gnome-3, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm working on a gnome-shell extension and I can't get the linear-gradient to work properly (or at all, in fact). The GTK [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html) or this [post](https://thegnomejournal.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/styling-gtk-with-css/) state that we should be able to use something like this:

```
label {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, blue 20%, #f0f 80%);

  /*OR*/

  background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear,
                                   0 0, 0 1,
                                   color-stop(0, @yellow),
                                   color-stop(0.2, @blue),
                                   color-stop(1, #0f0));
}
```

But it doesn't work, the gradient doesn't show up.

So far, the only way that I can get a gradient is if I use these undocumented properties:

```
label {
    background-gradient-start: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
    background-gradient-end: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
}
```

The problem is that I need to use the linear-gradient function to fine tune the gradient. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but Gnome Shell uses St for widgets which supports CSS, but I don't think it uses Gtk CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The first two don't work because GNOME did not yet implement multiple/custom color stops. You could try to create a GTK+ 2/3 theme and use classes from that instead, or create a few scalable images (like .svg) for what you need and use those instead.